# Handling force quit in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

When I force quit my app (by double-tapping the home button and swiping away its card) and then try to re-open the app, the app freezes. What type of housekeeping should be done so an app can still close gracefully even when it's killed via iOS 7?

Comment: Could you show some relevant code?

Comment: Why the app is "freezing" is the important thing here, and that could be one of a million things.  There is nothing inherent to force quitting that would cause this.  How your app loads its initial data is everything here, because however you are doing that obviously isn't working.  So based on the info given, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because you we're running in the debugger and the debugger is still attached. Click on the Stop button in the debugger and restart the app.